# Sorting CollectionViewSource using custom IComparer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to sort a collection derived from CollectionViewSource, which simply has SortDescriptions for sorting. Unfortunately I need to be able to use my own custom IComparer, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Think of a datagrid and I have my own multi-column sort algorithm. I'm thinking one way to do it is to use a collection implementing CollectionChanged that is an additional layer between the CollectionViewSource and my true datasource, but I would really prefer a better way if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bea Stollnitz has a custom sorting example [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120205143541/http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=24).

The key point of that article is to bind the `CollectionViewSource` to an `IList` implementation rather than a weaker `ICollection` or `IEnumerable` interface. With that, the `View` property returns a `ListCollectionView` instance instead of `CollectionView`. You can then use `ListCollectionView.CustomSort` to assign an `IComparer` to do your custom sorting. To make things easier, you can additionally use the [`Comparer<T>.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh737198.aspx) method to use a `Comparison` delegate instead of a whole class.

Comment: One addition: The use of `CustomSort` and `SortDescriptions` is mutually exclusive, you can't use both. Setting one clears the other automatically. So for a multi-column sort, this also needs to be handled by the custom comparer!